# jQuery Math Formula Issue - Incorrect result or NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm having some trouble with a little device I'm making that's meant to perform all the calculations for a luthier to build a perfect fretboard for a guitar.

http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/xqgGER

The program is on codepen, and so far the left half (fret distance calc) works fine, in spite of the spaghetti...I was tired.

But I'm having an issue with the final calculation on the right side (formula2):

```
  $("#fc_calc2").click(function() {

  var T = $("#frN_12").html()
  var St = $("input[id='St']").val()
  var Sn = $("input[id='Sn']").val()
  var X = (T) / ((St/Sn) - 1)
  $("#formula1").text(X.toFixed(3))

  var Rn = $("input[id='Rn']").val()
  var D = $("input[id='radius']").val()
  var Rd = ((Rn * (X + D)) / X)
  $("#formula2").text(Rd.toFixed(3));
  });
```

You can recreate the issue with the following values:

```
Scale Length = 25.1 (You must press this button to calculate the left side first)

(E to E @ Nut) = 1.406
(E to E @ 12th) = 1.719
(Nut Radius) = 12
(Radius Point) = 18.825
```

The issue presents in the Formula 2 field. With the radius point value with a decimal place, the result is NaN. With a whole number, it simply repeats the value of the Nut Radius (12).

I double checked that my formulas are correct - you can see the basis here: http://www.stewmac.com/How-To/Online_Resources/Neck_Building_and_Repair_and_Setup/Compound_Radius_Explained.html
At the bottom of the page, the issue is occurring with the second formula (2).

Any idea what's going on here? I'm not the greatest math magician in the world, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Joel

Comment: `.val()` always returns a **string**.  That `(X + D)` subexpression will therefore perform a string concatenation, not a numeric addition.

Comment: `val()` returns a string. You need to use `parseFloat()` to convert it to a floating point which can be used in a calculation

Comment: Has **nothing** to do with jQuery

Comment: @vsync An argument could be made. The problem itself stems from `.val()` and `.html()`, which are both jQuery functions. In the interest of tagging I wholeheartedly agree, just playing devil's advocate ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following lines:

```
var Rn = $("input[id='Rn']").val()
var D = $("input[id='radius']").val()
var St = $("input[id='St']").val()
var Sn = $("input[id='Sn']").val()
```

to

```
var Rn = parseFloat($("input[id='Rn']").val());
var D = parseFloat($("input[id='radius']").val());
var St = parseFloat($("input[id='St']").val());
var Sn = parseFloat($("input[id='Sn']").val());
```

And try again.

Explanation: The `NaN (Not-a-Number)` is a weirdo Global Object in javascript frequently returned when some mathematical operation failed. This property indicates that a value is not a legal number..

Comment: And the three lines in the first section, too: `var T`, `var St`, and `var Sn`.

Comment: `parseInt()` is probably not the right choice; either `parseFloat()` or, even better, just the unary `+` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - the parsefloat option worked out perfectly

Answer (score 3):

`val()` returns a string. Adding two strings just concatenates them. You can turn all your numeric strings into actual floating point numbers by using the unary `+` operator, as [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) mentioned in a separate comment.

```
var a = "1";
var b = "2";
console.log(a+b); //12
```

```
var a = +"1";
var b = +"2";
console.log(a+b); //3
```

---

```
$("#fc_calc2").click(function() {

  var T = +$("#frN_12").html()
  var St = +$("input[id='St']").val()
  var Sn = +$("input[id='Sn']").val()
  var X = (T) / ((St/Sn) - 1)
  $("#formula1").text(X.toFixed(3))

  var Rn = +$("input[id='Rn']").val()
  var D = +$("input[id='radius']").val()
  var Rd = ((Rn * (X + D)) / X)
  $("#formula2").text(Rd.toFixed(3));

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response - I took the parsefloat path, but between this and my JSON projects, I'm starting to see the console as a very useful tool :}

Comment: Yes, its a life saver :P